# is it possible to do tab completion in elm repl?

Tags: tabs, elm, read-eval-print-loop, completion

I am currently starting to use elm for web development. Using the repl it sems that there is no tab completion for common built functions, except for user defined. Is this really the case or am I missing something here? for example, in the example below I have to type everything, tabbing String. doesn't give any completion suggestions

```
   name="adam erik"

  "adam erik" : String
> String.length name
  9 : Int
```

so, is there any tab completion that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The current elm repl does NOT support tab completion.